# Spring Mvc - изучаю spring и не могу справиться с ошибкой , при запуске сервер выдает о Servlet.init() для сервлета [dispatcher] выбросил исключение

Tags: spring

если кто может мне помочь понять в чем причина буду очень благодарен , написал самую простую программу на Spring чтоб обработал GET запрос и выдал страничку , файл jsp index сервер открывает  а вот по URL запросы от Controller он выдает ошибку в чем может быть причина ? [![get запрос controller][1[![]][1[![]][1[image: ]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99p4y.png)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzglT.png)][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZBNE.png)

Comment: Во-первых, не добавляйте данные в виде скриншотов. Во-вторых, пользуйтесь, пожалуйста, грамматикой русского языка. В-третьих, отформатируйте вопрос.